# import the content of a form in wikipedia

Tags: php

I want to import de whole name frome this page ( http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_2012-heden&action=edit&section=1 )(from form) and then compare it with the names of this page (http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_2012-heden) and printout de relevante links  with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write some code to parse the HTML from the Wikipedia site.
The [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go to parse the HTML and get the information you need.
Once you have your data from the Wikipedia pages, you can compare them in your code.

Example to get the names (not tested, you probably need some more selectors to get exactly what you want):

```
ini_set('memory_limit','160M');
require('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file

$url = 'http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_2012-heden';

// Object oriented style
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);

// Procedural style
// $html = file_get_html($url);

$items = array();
// Find div with class editmode and loop through it.


foreach($html->find('div.editmode') as $article) {
        // Get all anchors in a unordened list with a list tag

        foreach($article->find('ul li a') as $a)
            $items[] = "<a href='". $a->href . "'>" . $a->plaintext . "</a>";

}


print_r($items);
```

If you see some weird characters in names (`AndrÃ© Bosman` for example), you should consider defining your charset (to UTF-8) in your html like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanks roy .my php does not recognize de find methode and file_get_html is there any alternatives ?or is there a way to import this functions?

Comment: You you included the simple_html_dom.php file? I have updated my answer with the object oriented simple_html_dom style. Maybe you could try that method? Also make sure that you don't run out of memory (add `ini_set('memory_limit','160M');` for example.

Comment: hi roy dank je voor je tijd .het lukt weer niet.hij kent simple_html_dom.php eigenlijk niet.daar heb ik een foutmelding voor gekregen   nogmaals bedankt voor je tijd

Comment: Hi Massood (please write in English for future readers) you need to download the [`simple_html_dom.php`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download) file and paste that file in the same directory as your script. That should solve the problem, if it doesn't please open a chat and I'll guide you through the process.

Comment: thank you roy.the problem is solved but i have another queastion and i prommise you it would be the last one.As you see we hava other candidators of different party but with div.editmode i can only put a row of them in a row .how can i have the whole candidators in de same array.  thank you

Comment: Hi Massood, I have updated my answer to list all candidates from all parties. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: hi roy. the previous version print de first row of VVD party but the new version print "Gekozen bij de verkiezingen van 12 september 2012" out not more

Comment: hi roy .i have delete de echo "<pre>" and it works complateley goed thanks for your time.nogmaals bedankt

Comment: hi roy dank je.One more q.Actually i have to have all this names as a link .after import the names we have to click on the names to have all the information of the candidates .the code is very helpful but it gives me only the array of names how can i have the names as link ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you, you can add some other HTML to the links as well if you need to.

Comment: Hi roy  i have done what u said but last two parties"Partij voor de Dieren" and "50 plus" has no "div" in html en i couldn't find any other way to download their member as previous parties.Is there any way to have last 4 members ?thank u